# Appendix labels in small caps and hyperref

Tags: fonts, hyperref, cross-referencing, appendices

I'm using the `book` class and I'd like appendix labels (letters) to be in small caps everywhere, particularly those generated by `\ref` and `\autoref`. I've tried doing it by redefining `\thechapter` after the `\appendix` command (or by patching the command in the preamble), but I run into an error with theorem headings if I use `hyperref`.

The example is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \appendix
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\textsc{\alph{chapter}}}
    \chapter{An appendix}
    \section{First section in the appendix} \label{sec:first}
    We refer to \ref{sec:first}.
    \begin{Theorem}[A theorem] Theorem text. \end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't compile, while if I remove `hyperref` it works and the label generated by `\ref` is correctly in small caps.

(In the actual document I get a different error which has to do with `microtype` and using Minion Pro, but it also disappears if I remove `hyperref` and redefine `\autoref` to be `\ref`.)

Is there some other way to change this? A solution which applies small caps only to the output of `\ref` and `\autoref` would be fine, since elsewhere (section and theorem headings and so on) the label is already in small caps in my actual document.

Comment: `\textsc` isn't expandable, this will break. Use `\scshape` instead. But why do you want to have lower case letters? And welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite of the non standard way: `\textsc` is a non-expandable command, this will break in conjunction with `hyperref`. The expandable form is `\scshape` (small caps shape).

The real problem is however, that `\chapter`, `\section` etc. use `\bfseries` to display the heading titles of of chapters etc. There is no bold small caps version of the standard fonts, so this will not display as small caps then, that's why `\thesection` and `\section` display `a` instead of `A`.

In my opinion `\alph` should be replaced by `\Alph` here!

> However, I don't recommend this `smallcaps` here at all, especially since `A` in small caps is smaller than the numbers.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Main matter chapter}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\scshape \alph{chapter}}}

\chapter{An appendix}
\section{First section in the appendix} \label{sec:first}
We refer to \ref{sec:first}.
\begin{Theorem}[A theorem] Theorem text. \end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @touhami: Yes, just wondered it did not work. I reset it

Comment: `\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\normalfont\scshape \alph{chapter}}}`

Comment: @touhami: Wouldn't that look strange in the chapter etc. titles?

Comment: yes i think it is

Comment: @touhami: I had that in mind, already, but as said: It's strange rather then.

Comment: there is fonts with bold smallcaps

Comment: @touhami: Yes, but that's another point. I have no idea what the final document should look like. I won't suggest another font in addition. The O.P. states that he uses Adobe Minion Pro. I've no idea whether that font has bold small caps

Comment: Thanks! With Minion Pro headings should be fine (and numbers are old-style so the height is fine too). However, the solution breaks if I also load `microtype` in the example above (even without `tracking=smallcaps`). Do you know what conflict there might be (it mentions `MT@res@a`? (By the way, should I edit my question to add `microtype` or leave this only in the comments?)

Comment: Yes, it's an issue with `microtype`. I think, it has to do with the font expansion, ultimately originating from the missing bold small caps in `cm` fonts. I don't have the Minion Pro fonts installed, so I can't test my idea.

Comment: I've just seen that in fact it occurs also if `\itshape` instead of `\scshape`, despite there being no missing font issue in that case. That might be easier to test. Thanks again

Comment: @TommasoPetrucciani: Well, I've got no clue for this right now